# Wondering what these patterns are on my pepper plants

Tags: peppers

[image: New Growth][image][image]Hello this is my first time growing peppers and I noticed my Giant Marconi plant has weird patterns on the leaves. At first I thought they were caused by mites or some other bug but the patterns are to uniform. As far as I know mites leave random trails not patterns. If anyone could help me identify the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a photo of the entire plant, especially the new growth.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly looks like a mosaic virus. Common examples are [Tobacco Mosaic Virus (TMV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobacco_mosaic_virus) and [Cucumber Mosaic Virus (CMV)](https://www.apsnet.org/edcenter/disandpath/viral/pdlessons/Pages/Cucumbermosaic.aspx).

The CMV link says

> Pepper fruit may develop ringspotting

Compare to [this](https://www.ipmimages.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5266084) photo of CMV. (Your photo is one of the most amazing examples of mosaic virus I ever have seen)

In either case no cure exists, and be careful as the disease easily infects  other species like tomatoes and cucumbers.

It is important to remove all parts of infected plants even dust from old dry leaves.

### Edit:

If the disease is affecting all the plants then it is likely a virus.
If it only affects some leaves, and not the new leaves (as indicated on the newly added photo), then you should investigate the case further before making any conclusion.
Especially look at the shade side of infected leaves.

Comment: I'd like to see if the new growth is chlorotic before making this diagnosis, because the OP should destroy the plants and not plant any Solanacaea in that garden for at least 3 (and better, 5) years if you're right.

Comment: Thank you for your response I added a few pictures of new growth, also the plant is flowering I'm not sure if that helps or not just thought I should state that.